# Template Class calling itself as argument in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, constructor

I know the title is a little confusing but I will try to explain what I mean.

So, think you have a class **Foo** and it has some template variables. It is something like :

```
class A
{
public:
    A();
    ~A();
};

template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    //These are my constructors.
    Foo();
    Foo(T);
    Foo(T*, int); //This is for something else.

    T var;
}
```

But in main function, I want to have something like this :

```
Foo<Foo<A>> multiFoos;
```

And Visual Studio says

```
"no default constructor exists for Foo<Foo<A>>"
```

So, I hope my question is quite clear and you can help me with this.

Thanks,

Comment: [Compiles for me](http://rextester.com/MFJ55086) (assuming that missing semicolon is a typo)

Comment: Consider writing a mcve.

Comment: [Looks fine to me aswell.](http://ideone.com/F65Sw3)

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I changed something in my code. Actually I had another class which is called in Foo<Foo<A>> instead of Foo<Foo<int>>  @user2079303

Comment: [Still compiles with MSVC11](http://rextester.com/IIF86130)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to write default constructor in my original code. After I wrote, it worked. Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: And this is why you should write the mcve before posting on stackoverflow.